# Variable not transferring from one PHP page to another

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have recently migrated my site to a server with a newer PHP version of PHP 5.3. Everything seems to be working fine, except that I can no longer send a variable between two PHP pages through the JavaScript code that was working before.

I have a `.php` file with the following command:

```
href='http://www.example.com/Music/Update/update22.php?FixedIDvalue={$row['FixedID']}'
```

It sends the numerical value contained in FixedIDvalue to `update22.php`

`update22.php` GETS this value and sends it to a MySQL database - it works fine.

However, the `class='votepos'` statement takes this variable and first processes it through a `.js` file, before sending it to the aforementioned `update22.php`, enabling the site to run a few commands that hides the clunky redirecting process.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".votepos").click(function(event){
    var vote = $(this).attr('href').replace('http://www.example.com/Music/Update/update22.php?FixedIDvalue=', '');
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.example.com/Music/Update/update22.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {FixedIDvalue:vote},
            success: function(data) {
            window.location.reload(false);
            }
        });
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This JavaScript was previously sending the FixedIDvalue to `update22.php`, but now it doesn't seem to be doing so, and I don't know why.

If I remove the `class='votepos'` from the orignal PHP statement, or REM out the JavaScript in the HTML header then the variable transmits between one PHP file and the other PHP file as you would expect, but when it transmits the variable through the `.js` script, it no longer receives the variable - or at least it doesn't seem to.

Any ideas?
Do I need to explain the issue in other words?
Please let me know,
Richard.

Comment: I have no idea what you're intending `class=...` to do here. That's for CSS.

Comment: @tadman the class is used as a selector for the jQuery there. `$(".votepos")` selects all elements that have the class `votepos`.

Comment: `.replace('http://www.example.com/Music/Update/update22.php?FixedIDvalue=', '')` and `http://www.example.com/file.php?FixedIDvalue` do not match so vote will not be an integer. Or you didn't copy and paste the script into the question, which would be the most helpful thing to do... In any case it would be more sensible to get the variable by parsing the URL not by replacing what may or may not be the correct string with empty.

Comment: Why not add a "data" element to the link as an attribute and pass the value that way. href='http://www.example.com/file.php?FixedIDvalue' class='votepos' data='FixedIDvalue'

Comment: Thanks Popnoodles, I'm looking at those two URLs right now... Yes, I simplified the address in the first .php statement above. It should read:
    href='http://www.example.com/Music/Update/update22.php?FixedIDvalue={$row['FixedID']}'

Any ideas?
It was working OK yesterday and the days before.

Comment: I've now inserted the correct URL, sorry about that.

Comment: Code seems fine but In ajax both url should be in same format. like if in url `www` is there so u can use `www` in post url.

Comment: Your onclick selector is using the class "votepos".  Does your html element still have class="votepos" href="foo..."?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, Koushik, sorry.

Chris, yes, the HTML element still has the class="votepos" statement at the end of it. I haven't changed anything.

As I said, it 'appears' to be working, but the FixedIDvalue variable is not being send to the MySQL table, which, as far as I can see, means that the destination .php file isn't getting this variable, or if it gets it, doesn't know what to do with it.

Is there any way I can troubleshoot, to see if the .php destination file is receiving the variable?

Comment: Hello again,
Thanks for your collective help, I appear to have found a solution.

I changed the ´type: 'post'´ statement to ´type: 'get'´.

As far as I can tell, PHP 5.3 no longer accepts global variables, which means posting that variable from the ´.js´ to the PHP will not yield results. The ´.js´ file does its posting just just fine, but the .php file doesn't handle it properly.
Anyhow, I also added ´$FixedIDvalue = $_GET['FixedIDvalue'];´ into the receiving .php file and it now seems to be working (for now!).

Any comments, please go ahead.

Comment: BTW, thanks for bronze badges :)